# Associating multiple objects in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application that tracks exercises and workouts and I'm having trouble associating them in the controller. I would like to associate an array of exercises with a given individual workout.  The problem I have is with the create action of the controller.  I have included the other files for context.

I haven't seen any examples that go through building associations with more than a single other instance of a model.  In the Rails console, I can easily associate them by doing

`ex = Exercise.all.last`

`workout = Workout.all.last`

`workout.exercises.push(ex)`

`workout.exercises` # lists all exercises

How is this done in the controller?

I have consulted the Rails Getting Started Guides but their discussion doesn't talk about HABT relationships.  I have consulted the RailsCasts but a lot of the information is from before Rails 4.  I have also searched through other Stack questions and haven't been able to find what is probably a very simple example of how this works.

Schema:

```
create_table "exercises", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string  "name"
 t.integer "reps"
 t.integer "sets"
 t.string  "primary"
 t.string  "other"
end

create_table "exercises_workouts", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer "exercise_id"
 t.integer "workout_id"
end

create_table "workouts", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.string   "category"
end
```

Models:

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :workouts
end

class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :exercises
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for [@workout] do |f| %>
...

<% if @exercises.any? %>
<% @exercises.each do |exercise| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "workout[exercise_ids][]", nil %>
  <%= check_box_tag "workout[exercise_ids][]", exercise.id,
  @workout.exercise_ids.include?(exercise.id), id: dom_id(exercise) %>
  <%= label_tag dom_id(exercise), exercise.name %><br>
<% end %>
<% end %>
...
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    get_exercises
end

def create
    @workout = Workout.new(workout_params)
    @workout.exercises.push(params[:exercise_ids])

    if @workout.save
        flash[:success] = "Successfully created workout!"
        redirect_to @workout
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

...
  def workout_params
   params.require(:workout).permit(:category)
  end
```

This errors out because of a
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in WorkoutsController#create Exercise(#70125693469000) expected, got NilClass(#70125638586940)`

**Attempt 2**

I now avoid the error but it doesn't build the relationship.  I tried:

```
@workout.exercise_ids.push(params[:exercise_ids])
```

**Attempt 3**

I now see the params are being passed in and I have attempted this:

```
@workout.exercises.push(params[:workout][:exercise_ids])
```

**Attempt 4**

Made another attempt but it doesn't save

```
@workout = Workout.new(workout_params)

private

    def workout_params
     params.require(:workout).permit(:category, :exercise_id)
    end
```

**Attempt 5**

I made another attempt trying to be explicit about the exercises I wanted to be passed in. This however, had the weird affect of making the view not recognize the @exercises variable.  Not sure why that is the case.

```
@workout.exercises.build(params[:exercise_ids])
```

I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks

**Attempt 6**

I thought that because in the console I can push the exercises on, I could do the same thing in the controller. No dice.

```
@workout.exercises.push(params[:exercise_ids])
```

**Attempt 7**

After reviewing [ruby on rails - how to make relationship works in route, controller, view ? has_many, belongs_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937989/ruby-on-rails-how-to-make-relationship-works-in-route-controller-view-has), I tried to adapt my code in the following way:

```
@workout = Workout.new
@workout = @workout.exercises.build(params[:workout_params])

...

  def workout_params
    params.require(:workout).permit(:category, :exercise_ids)
  end
```

However, this throws in error in the view layer: `undefined method`category' for #`.

**Attempt 8**

I tried:

```
    @workout = Workout.new.exercises.build(params[:workout_params])
```

Comment: I'm just glossing over your code, but I think the problem / issue may be with your models.  Your using 2 HABTM relationships, but I could be wrong  ...just a suggestion.

Comment: Why would that be a problem?  I'm new to Rails so I was following the Guide's suggestion: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: First step: look at the log and find out what parameters you got in your create message. Understand them. Then recheck your code, including workout_params method. I can spot at least two errors.

Comment: I've used debugger and the exercise params are accessed through `params[:workout][:exercise_ids]`.  My problem is I don't know the Rails controller association syntax for joining these two items.

Comment: I think I understand the idea but I don't know the syntax.  I know that I have to grab those exercise ids from the params passed from the form.  I have to whitelist them in my workout_params method and then I have to push them onto the exercises container for the workout.  I just don't know the syntax of how that happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails nested forms with pre-defined fields as checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928411/rails-nested-forms-with-pre-defined-fields-as-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Workout.create!(workout_params)
```

And `workout_params` should contain this:

```
def workout_params
  params.require(:workout).permit(:category, :exercise_ids => [])
end
```

You can also look into HABTM documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference.

Comment: Still not going through for me.  The form passes but if I inspect the workout it doesn't have any exercises in it.  I know that the form is retrieving them but they aren't getting associated.

Comment: Started POST "/workouts" for ::1 at 2015-09-20 13:35:29 -0700
Processing by WorkoutsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tj9+/7iXOfgtxdmVtBq6EskuM3g4smzWPKl6hABisp1mC8I8Q1XQMNhrShlzwUH2qAxv9Rs2ceoE08UFVnMCEQ==", "workout"=>{"category"=>"Fitness", "exercise_ids"=>["", "2", "", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Create Workout"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: exercise_ids

Comment: I couldn't put all of it, but exercise_ids is an unpermitted parameter even though I whitelisted it in `def workout_params
    params.require(:workout).permit(:category, :exercise_ids)
  end`

Comment: Well, I used the console to double check.  I ran this: `Workout.all.last.exercises.count` and it got back 0.

Comment: Oh, I think I understood the issue, check my updated answer.

Comment: That was it!  I really, really appreciate your patience working with a beginner.